# Maven plugin for building an IntelliJ plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, intellij-plugin

I have an IntelliJ plugin which build by Gradle https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin. Does Maven have such a plugin to build intellij plugin?

Comment: No, there is no such Maven plugin.